# Concatenate the files present in .m3u8 in python

Tags: python, concatenation, m3u8

I am trying to concatenate .ts files present in a .m3u8 playlist in python,

Is there any way of doing it ??? If yes please do explain how

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to concatenate? .ts file are mpeg-2 streams, while .m3u8 are textfiles?

Comment: I wanna concatenate .ts files which are video files

Comment: Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work, I only added two comments to this short script cause I guess it's pretty much self-explanatory.

```
import shutil

# Parse playlist for filenames with ending .ts and put them into the list ts_filenames
with open('playlist.m3u8', 'r') as playlist:
    ts_filenames = [line.rstrip() for line in playlist
                    if line.rstrip().endswith('.ts')]

# open one ts_file from the list after another and append them to merged.ts
with open('merged.ts', 'wb') as merged:
    for ts_file in ts_filenames:
        with open(ts_file, 'rb') as mergefile:
            shutil.copyfileobj(mergefile, merged)
```

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the reply.....the m3u8 file which I am using is online as a link....which won't work with this solution....:/

Comment: well .....I was able to solve that issue......but could you tell me.....where will the merged.ts be saved ??

Comment: It will be saved to the dir where you started the script. But you are free to specify a path, just be aware to use a raw string on windows so you don't have to escape the backslashes. e.g. open(r'C:\path\to\merged.ts', 'wb'). BTW Please be so kind to vote this answer up if it was helpful to you.

Comment: I can't vote up....not enough reputation for that....and thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I don't think it is sufficient. Concatenating the files from the command line does not work. I think you have to extract the video and audio streams and re-encapsulate them

Comment: robertspierre: you're wrong, that anwer works perfectly and its shortest I've found