# Merging ts video files using Python

Tags: python

I am using [m3u8 Python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/m3u8/0.2.4) to parse m3u8 and download ts video files into disk as in the following script:

```
import m3u8, urllib
playlist = "https://sevenwestmedia01-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/224853/TEST1/master_lowl.m3u8"

while True:
   m3u8_obj = m3u8.load(playlist)
   ts_segments_str = str(m3u8_obj.segments)
   for line in ts_segments_str.splitlines():
       if "https://" in line:
           ts_id = line[-20:]
           testfile = urllib.URLopener()
           testfile.retrieve(line, ts_id)
```

Is there a Python library that merges ts files together without using FFmpeg ?

Comment: you've already seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377674/concatenate-the-files-present-in-m3u8-in-python?

Answer (score 6):

In case of a necessary, you may use my script as well

```
import requests
import m3u8
import shutil
import os


def strip_end(text, suffix):
    if not text.endswith(suffix):
        return text
    return text[:len(text)-len(suffix)]


def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    # NOTE the stream=True parameter
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(f"ts_files/{local_filename}", 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

    return local_filename


m3u8_url = 'your m3u8 url goes here'
r = requests.get(m3u8_url)
m3u8_master = m3u8.loads(r.text)
# print(m3u8_master.data['segments'])
m3u8_file = m3u8_url.split('/')[-1]
url = strip_end(m3u8_url, m3u8_file)
url_copy = url

if not os.path.exists('ts_files'):
    print('ts_file folder is not found, creating the folder.')
    os.makedirs('ts_files')

# print statement can be deleted, they were placed prior to debugging purposes.
for seg in m3u8_master.data['segments']:
    print(url)
    url += seg['uri']
    print(url)
    print(f'downloading {seg["uri"]}')
    # download_file(url)  # comment out this line to download ts files.
    url = url_copy
    print(url)
    print()


# you should comment out the rest part if you want to merge your multiple ts files to one ts file.
"""
cwd = os.getcwd()  # Get the current working directory (cwd)
TS_DIR = 'ts_files'
with open('merged.ts', 'wb') as merged:
    for ts_file in os.listdir(f'{cwd}/{TS_DIR}'):
        with open(f'{cwd}/{TS_DIR}/{ts_file}', 'rb') as mergefile:
            shutil.copyfileobj(mergefile, merged)
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys, urllib2
import socks
from sockshandler import SocksiPyHandler
from urlparse import urlparse
from urllib import urlopen

i=0
    while i<1000:
        ' url from m3u8
        filename=filename+str(i)+'.ts'
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        ts = opener.open(filename).read()
        ' append stream to file
        tsfile = open(file, 'ab')
        tsfile.write(ts)
        print 'part %s done!' % i   
        i=i+1
```

Comment: Explain the answer please.